# How do I use a variable as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print myRandom (random number) as a string in the middle of the circle I created. Everything is working correctly besides when i use this code,    "[object HTMLDivElement" shows up in the middle instead of the number that it is creating. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
    #background{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size:cover;
    }


    #circle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
    }


    #number {
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="background"> </div>
    <div id="circle"> 
        <div id="number"> 11 </div> 
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var myRandom = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // max 100

    var myRandom2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 359) + 0; // max 359
    console.log(myRandom2);

    var circleNumber =  myRandom + 50;
    console.log(circleNumber);

    var myNumber = 
    document.querySelector("#number")
    myNumber.style.fontSize = myRandom + "px";
    myNumber.style.lineHeight = circleNumber + "px";

    var myCircle = 
    document.querySelector("#circle");
    myCircle.style.width = circleNumber + "px";
    myCircle.style.height = circleNumber + "px";

    var myColors =
    document.querySelector("#background")
    myColors.style.backgroundColor = "hsla("+myRandom2+", 100%, 48%, 1)"

    var myColors2 =
    document.querySelector("#circle")
    myColors2.style.backgroundColor = "hsla("+myRandom2+", 60%, 21%, 1)";

    var myText =
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = myNumber;
</script>
```

I added my entire code, but the issue is at the very bottom. I figured it would be helpful to see pretty much everything to see if I need to change anything above as well. But like I said before everything is working fine besides the last line of code, which I have surfed the internet to try and find and they just tell me to use the String() function.

Comment: try myNumber.innerHTML

Comment: I am still getting the "[object HTMLDivElement" in the middle text with myNumber.innerHTML.

Comment: var myText = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = myNumber.innerHTML; it works to me. showing 11 in middle, inside random sized circle.

Comment: It is showing 11 because of <div id="number"> 11 </div> . The inner html is by default "11". I need it to show the random number being generated through the variable myNumber.

Comment: I misunderstood. so you want to display circleNumber? var myText =
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = circleNumber;

Comment: Hmmm. That seems to work. But it isn't the "myNumber" variable. Weird that one variable would work, but another wouldn't.

Comment: I managed to fix it by creating a variable.

var randomString = myRandom;

and then did:

 myText.innerHTML = randomString;


I am not sure why myNumber was giving me such a weird error. But another variable seemed to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: myNumber variable references to DivElement named 'number' inside HTML. => var myNumber = document.querySelector("#number"); It is not a random number variable you created. Also, in last sentence, document.getElementById("number") also references to same DivElement. So you can write that sentence as var myText = myNumber.innerHTML = circleNumber;

Comment: Oh, I see. I inserted myNumber variable instead of myRandom. Simple mistake on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last line, you are using the wrong variable, use `myRandom` instead of `myNumber`. `myNumber` is the style and font, where `myRandom` is the random number. You can use 3 variables in your code actually: `myRandom`, `myRandom2` and `circleNumber`.

```
var myText =
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = myRandom;
```

Comment: OHHHH! That was just a mess up on my part. Been working on this code for too long I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the variable myNumber isn't a number, in fact it is  class, 
You could 
try to cast

```
var myText =
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = (int) myNumber;
```

Or get inner html of myNumber

```
var myText =
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = myNumber.innerHTML;
```